# Add new column to MySQL through JPA

Tags: mysql, jpa, code-generation

I would like to add a new column to MySQL table using JPA. How can I achieve it?

My concern is, even though the table can be updated, how can I update the entity so the column is usable for query by using JPA? or is there any other solution?

Comment: I think the easiest solution might be to find a way around having a need for the user to modify the database schema.  Can you clue us in on the business logic?

Comment: Since the user (client) is not able to communicate with the database schema directly, so that's why I wish to implement such way to allow to update database at client side...

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question.  _Why_ should the client ever be allowed to modify the database schema?  If, for example, adding a new column is allowed, then how to protect against malicious attacks?  You now have to worry about rogue users coming in and exploding the table by creating thousands of columns.

Comment: Yes, you are right, there is only authorized person can do such action, I will implement the security measure.  Now, back to the question, is it possible to add column from client side?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways of doing it, mostly through properties in `persistence.xml`. One standard way would be using `javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-script-source`, which may or may not be run every time you start the webapp, most likely leading to exceptions on start-up and possibly the destruction of your data.

In Hibernate, you can make it update your tables according to your entities using the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `update`.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl

In EclipseLink there is the `eclipselink.ddl-generation` property. The `create-or-extend-tables` settings seems appropriate.

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_ddl_generation.htm

However, generally speaking, using JPA to maintain your schema is less reliable than manually updating it with a pre-written script at the time of updating the production server's webapp.

Answer (score 0):

JPA doesn't provide for "on-the-fly" schema updates (and certainly not for dynamic updates to entity classes).

Some providers will allow addition of columns when the EMF is created (DataNucleus JPA does, for example), when the entity class can be reloaded. That is all there is. Other than that, re-architect your application

Comment: Hmm...got it, maybe re-architect is only the way. Thank you.